# Improving NFS client performance

Tags: network, thunderbolt, mount, sharing, nfs

I have my Macbook Pro (MacOS Mojave) connecting to an NFS share on a Linux machine directly connected via Thunderbolt with jumbo frames. Testing with `iperf3`, I can do ~14 Gbps (~1.8 GBps) over the connection, so I expect that network is not the bottleneck.

Here is the `/etc/exports`:

```
/srv/share         169.254.0.*(rw,sync,insecure,rw,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,no_subtree_check)
```

Doing some simple testing with `dd`, here is what I see:

#### Direct to disk on the server (~800MB/s)

```
~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/testfile bs=5120 count=100000
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 0.62477 s, 820 MB/s
```

#### NFS from the server (~660 MB/s)

I connected a client on the server to see how it performed with a Linux client and taking the network out of the equation.

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o rw 169.254.0.1:/srv/share /tmp/share
$ nfsstat -m
/tmp/share from 169.254.0.1:/srv/share
 Flags: rw,relatime,vers=4.2,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=169.254.0.1,local_lock=none,addr=169.254.0.1
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/share/test_file bs=5120 count=100000
100000+0 records in
100000+0 records out
512000000 bytes (512 MB, 488 MiB) copied, 0.76516 s, 669 MB/s
```

#### From Macbook Pro over Thunderbolt (~150MBps)

I tried to match the default NFS client connection from Linux, but the Mac client doesn't support the same options. I've tried `vers=3` and even `async`, but am never able to get it much faster than this.

```
$ sudo mount -t nfs -o rw,vers=4,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys 169.254.0.1:/srv/share /srv/share
$ nfsstat -m
/srv/share from 169.254.0.1:/srv/share
  -- Original mount options:
     General mount flags: 0x0
     NFS parameters: vers=4,proto=tcp,hard,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys
     File system locations:
       /srv/share @ 169.254.0.1 (169.254.0.1)
  -- Current mount parameters:
     General mount flags: 0x4000000 multilabel
     NFS parameters: vers=4.0,proto=tcp,port=2049,hard,nointr,noresvport,callback,negnamecache,nonamedattr,noacl,noaclonly,locks,noquota,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,readahead=16,dsize=32768,nordirplus,nodumbtimr,timeo=600,maxgroups=16,acregmin=5,acregmax=60,acdirmin=5,acdirmax=60,nomutejukebox,noephemeral,nonfc,sec=sys
     File system locations:
       /srv/share @ 169.254.0.1 (169.254.0.1)
     Status flags: 0x0
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/share/testfile bs=5120 count=10000
10000+0 records in
10000+0 records out
51200000 bytes transferred in 0.337533 secs (151688873 bytes/sec)
```

---

Given how fast the network is, it seems like I should be able to get 3-4x the speeds I'm seeing from the Mac. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Are all your devices configured for the use of 'jumbo frames' because a mixture of devices configured for jumbo frames and devices not configured for jumbo frames on a network has the potential to cause network performance issues.

Comment: Yes, both are using jumbo frames https://gist.github.com/ipmb/c8ca58662685c1b0846351b3102908d6

Comment: Have you tried another data transfer speed test? I find DD on macOS somewhat inaccurate in certain scenarios.

Comment: I tried to run bonnie++, but the share consistently drops part way through the test. If I just `cp` a 512MB file, the timings are approx: Direct: 20ms, Local NFS: 180ms, NFS from Mac: 300ms. I also timed the rsync of a large `.git` directory and got: Direct: 0.2s, Local NFS: 1.2s, NFS from Mac: 3.5s.

Answer (score 1):

i was having a lot of trouble with both transfer speed to/from an NFS share, as well as extremely slow performance traversing directories; after mounting a share, listing a directory containing just 5 items would take several seconds..
Accessing the same share via smb was much faster..

i finally found a 'fix' that helped me after looking [here](https://dl.acronis.com/u/vstorage/docs/html/AcronisSoftwareDefinedInfrastructure_2_users_guide_en-US/accessing-networkfs/mounting-nfs-exports-on-macos.html), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252578957), and [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/browsing-nfs-shares-extremely-slow-and-hang-finder.1518545/):

Find out which version of NFS protocol is in place on the server; in may case, it's 3..

Now, in the file:

```
/etc/nfs.conf
```

add the following line:

```
nfs.client.mount.options=nolocks,locallocks,vers=3
```

Save and restart..
NFS performance should be much improved..

Noting that you change *3* in the line above to whatever version of the protocol your NFS server is using..

EDIT: i just changed the version number (vers=3) in the answer from 4.1 to 3.. Both seem to work fine for me, but it has been suggested in the comments below that 4.1 is not actually a real option since the macOS NFS client goes up to 4.. One last note, using vers=4 breaks my mounts, but ymmv..

Comment: On Sonoma 14.4, I get an error `illegal NFS version value -- 4.1`

Comment: Have you tried a different version, like 3? i'm also having tons of issues with NFS in Sonoma, though i'm still on Sonoma 14.3.1

Comment: @luckman212 4.0 is the latest NFS version supported by macOS (→ vers=4).

Comment: it's odd because if i pu 'vers=4' or 'vers=4.0', it breaks my mounts; but 3 or 4.1 work fine for me (form Mojave to Sonoma 14.3.1)..